# typedef and template parameter with same name

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, typedef, ambiguous

Why is that case incorrect (it's logical)

```
template <typename T>
struct Der: public Base
{
    typedef int T;
    T val;
};
```

, but that case is correct?

```
struct Base
{
    typedef int T;
};

template <typename T>
struct Der: public Base
{
    T val;
};
```

The Standard 14.6.1/7 says:

> In the definition of a class template or in the definition of a member of such a template that appears outside of the template definition, for each base class which does not depend on a template-parameter (14.6.2), if the name of the base class or the name of a member of the base class is the same as the name of a template-parameter, the base class name or member name hides the template-parameter name (3.3.7).

Why is it not ambiguous in here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first example is incorrect according to [temp.local]/6:

> A *template-parameter* shall not be redeclared within its scope (including nested scopes).

However, in

```
template <typename T>
struct Der: public Base
{
    T val;
};
```

`T` is hidden by the name inherited from `Base` - as specified *by your quote*.

> [..] **if** the name of the base class or **the name of a member of
>   the base class is the same as the name of a *template-parameter*, the
>   base class name or member name hides the *template-parameter* name
>   (3.3.7)**.

That is, the member `val` is of type `int`. [**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5c6ab317d38065c).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what are the reasons for such behavior?

Comment: @user3514538 Redeclaring a template-parameter would probably lead to problems with [basic.scope.class]/1 - an important paragraph. Not to mention the ODR. However, concerning the second bit, I'm not sure. We should wait for hvd :o)

Comment: This seems to be subject of [CWG 591](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#591), though that only restricts this rule to non-dependent base classes.

Comment: And the whole thing is subject of [CWG 459](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#459).

Comment: @dyp I hoped that someone had written a CWG issue. It didn't really make sense to me either.

Comment: Well, as it's said in the discussion, it seems to "fall straightforwardly out of the lookup rules". That is, lookup rules for template parameters are a bit weird, their "scope" is compared to namespace scope in the discussion of the issue (but IMHO that's unintuitive).

Answer (score 3):

In general, the standard tries to ensure that the meaning of a type in
a given scope is the same.

If we pretend that the typedef is allowed then consider the types of `val1`, `val2`, and `val3` in the following?

```
template <typename T>
struct Der: public Base
{
    void f1() {
      T val1;      // What is the type of 'val1'?
    }

    T val2;        // What is the type of 'val2'?

    typedef int T;

    T val3;        // What is the type of 'val3'?
};
```

The only variable to have the template parameter type T would be
'val2'.

This is because the standard requires that all members of the class be "in scope" for `f1`.  This is why member functions can refer to member variables defined later in the class body.

The same problem can be demonstrated with typedefs too:

```
typedef int T;

struct S
{
  T x;
  typedef float T;
  T y;
};
```

Again, if this was legal then the `T` used for the declaration of `x` would refer to `::T` and the `T` used for `y` would refer to typedef `S::T`.

This is covered by the standard under ISO 3.3.7/1:

> The following rules describe the scope of names declared in classes.
>
> ...
>
> 2) A name N used in a class S shall refer to the same declaration in its context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of S. No diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule.

Answer (score 1):

Because the second is unambigous:

You might not care or know that there was the `typedev int T` in the superclass, but you've just introduced `T` as template parameter, which makes it clear that you're referring to it when using `T` in `Der`.

Comment: The `T` in derived is actually the member of the base, `Base::T`, in the second example.  This would appear to contradict your answer - or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think this answer is _wrong_ per se, but it doesn't really explain anything either.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `T` refers to the base class typedef. The answer says *"you've just introduced `T` as template parameter, which makes it clear that you're referring to it when using `T` in Der."*

Comment: @Columbo: That's no more true than it is in the first case. This answer doesn't explain why the template parameter `T` should magically gain precedence just because the other `T` is inherited from a base (despite this fact being true).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Um, I tried to make a point of the coder expressing his explicit desire to introduce the name 'T', which makes the "right" behaviour "obvious".

Comment: @MarcusMüller: The code explicitly introduced both names 'T', in both cases. There's nothing "obvious" about which one should take precedence! Nope, not even when one is lexically closer.